# Why is the installation location of python3 on MacOS different than described in the official docs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I installed Python 3.8.2 on my Mac (macOS Big Sur 11.3.1) using [the official Python installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/macOS).

According to [the official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/mac.html), this means my Python should live here:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Additionally, I should have a `Python 3.8` folder in my `/Applications` directory. But I don't have either:

#### `/Applications`

```sh
➜  /Applications pwd
/Applications
➜  /Applications ls -al
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  28 root    admin   896 May 28 15:48 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 root    wheel   640 Jan  1  2020 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 martin  admin  6148 May 28 15:48 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 root    wheel     0 Jan  1  2020 .localized
--snip--
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Apr 25 18:37 OneTab.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Mar 27 18:41 Pages.app
drwxr-xr-x   3 root    admin    96 May 15 09:41 PostgreSQL 13
drwxr-xr-x@  3 martin  admin    96 Feb 11 17:48 Postgres.app
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root    wheel    96 Jan  1  2020 Safari.app
--snip--
```

#### `/Library/Frameworks/`

```sh
➜  Frameworks pwd
/Library/Frameworks
➜  Frameworks ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  wheel    96 Jan  1  2020 .
drwxr-xr-x  66 root  wheel  2112 May 22 15:29 ..
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    50 Jan  1  2020 iTunesLibrary.framework -> /System/Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework
```

After some digging, and the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56441098/5717580), I found the new Python installation in:

```sh
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework
```

Why is the installation location nested in the `Developer/CommandLineTools/` subdirectory instead of the one described in the docs?

Comment: Because both Mac and Python are a pain (and version management is difficult), imo. You might consider using pyenv to install and manage various non-Mac-default Python environments.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod that's actually what I'm doing. I installed `pyenv` and was hunting down an older Python version I had installed previously with the installer in order to remove it. Took a while until I found it (and was a bit confusing, hence the question) :P

Comment: For me, pyenv installs under `$(pyenv root)/versions` (which is `~/.pyenv/versions/`).

Comment: Yes if you install it using `pyenv`. The installation I'm talking about was done with [the official Python installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/), not with `pyenv`.

Comment: The doco thinks Intel CPUs on Macs are "new" so (the bulk of) it was apparently written a very long time ago. (Some parts mention Python 3.9 and have thus probably been routinely updated later.)